# Export Power BI report to Azure Data Lake using Python

Tags: python, powerbi

Looking forward to export PBIX\Power BI reports from Power BI workspace to Azure Data Lake, I have come across below cmdlet in PowerShell that allows us to do the same, however do we have an equivalent library or a function in Python that can do so?

```
Export-PowerBIReport
      [-WorkspaceId <Guid>]
      -Id <Guid>
      -OutFile <String>
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

Have tried below in python:

Will it be possible to export the file in GEN2, can you provide an example if you have it handy please? Here is what I have tried:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/test/reports/testid')

with open('text.pbix','wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not an official Python SDK for this, but it's all based on the REST APIs that you can hit from any language or platfom.

The API is [Reports - Export To File In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file-in-group)

Comment: Thanks! Modified my post with the python code I am using, the test.pbix file is getting exported as 0 bytes, do I need to append anything in the post URL? Also, would like to understand where the file will be saved by default if I run the API call from Azure Synapse?